# Change color of the Angular Material pagination select when focused

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to style my table with pagination in Angular and override the default colors, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I tried to play with it in the Chrome Developer tools and tried to apply a few styles, but without any result.

```
// 1. Option
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: red !important;
}

// 2. Option
mat-focused .mat-form-field-label { color: red !important; }
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline .mat-form-field-ripple { background: red !important; }


// 3. Option - This at least changed the color of the option, but not active/selected option
::ng-deep .mat-select-value {
  color: red !important;
}
```

[image: Material Pagination Active]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Which element you want to force change? the background of the page size shown above in grey or the blue line?

Comment: Blue line under and also selected/active option (number 20)

Comment: cool, please checkout the link and screenshot below and follow the steps indicated in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the right selectors (class-names) and force your new styles by penetrating default material colors for the background of the `.mat-select-panel .mat-option.mat-selected` and `.mat-form-field-ripple` by prefixing the respective class names with `::ng-deep`. Although you attempt to use it above but you are not accessing the correct DOM elements you wish to force change.

Putting this theoretical concepts in actions you need to add these `css`  specs to your component's style-sheet.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-multiple) {
  background: #02a10e;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: #04c431;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what you desire to achieve:

[image]

And here is a [Stackblitz playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-paginator-sawpat?file=app/table-pagination-example.css) to see this in action.

Comment: Thanks a lot, working like expected. Here is just a code to also update little arrow's color - `::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused.mat-primary .mat-select-arrow { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this CSS, and you are done

```css
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-page-size { 
  ::ng-deep .mat-select-value {   // this is to change color of page size text in mat paginator
    color: inherit !important;
  }

  ::ng-deep .mat-select-trigger {   // this is to change color of page size text in mat paginator
    color: inherit !important;
  }

  ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {    // this is to change color of arrow beside pagesize in mat paginator
    color: inherit !important;
  }   
}
```