# How to change mat-paginator border bottom color?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm trying to style the border bottom color of my mat-paginator when a option is selected, which has a default purple color. Anyone got a solution?

[Mat-paginator purple border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPNAu.png)

I tried looking for class that style the border on devtools, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to target the mat-form-field-ripple class and use ng-deep or place the rules in styles.css to override the theme based color,

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to override everywhere, use this in the styles.css

```
.mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-bottom-color: red !important;
}
```

And in case you want to override it just in one particular component, add the ::ng-deep as follows:

```
::ng-deep {
  .mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-bottom-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587176/change-color-of-the-angular-material-pagination-select-when-focused) (possibly a duplicate).